# Definite article with heart, body etc

Tags: definite-article

Can you explain why "the" is used in these nouns? Shouldn't it instead use "a" because they're mentioned for the first time?

> **The heart** pumps blood around **the body**.

> Running is good for **the heart**.

> **The heart**, like **the stomach**, needs diet

> **The lungs** transfer oxygen into **the blood**.

> **The blood** carries oxygen to all parts of **the body**

Answer (score 4):

You would choose **a** if you were thinking of an individual **heart** or **body**. Here, you choose **the** to indicate that you are referring to the entire class represented by **heart** or **body**.

Swales and Feak (*Academic Writing for Graduate Students*) call this the *abstract generic* use of **the**. They offer the following examples, which seem to match yours:

> *The wasp* can detect unique volatile compounds over great distances.
> *The computer* has been invaluable in scientific advancement.
> *The elephant* has come dangerously close to extinction.

This is in contrast to the *concrete abstract* use of **a**. These examples might suggest the difference:

> A motivated elephant can outrun a human.
> A heart with a defect might pump blood inefficiently.

In these cases, we are not thinking of the class as a whole but rather individuals — even if what we say is true of the class.

Comment: Which heart/lungs/body/blood/stomach is the speaker referring to?

Comment: @Nyambek - how many hearts have you got?

Comment: He is referring to every heart. What is true of the class is true of the individual. Note that this is a very subtle use of articles. You can't treat it as if it worked logically. Other languages that use articles might not use them in this way.

Comment: Also, we generally use _the_ to refer to an organ as part of a person. _He was shot in the leg. She has cancer of the colon. He kissed her on the lips_.